# Accessing Rows and columns of an internal/client side SQLite database Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have searched High Low right and left for this answer and I have come up empty handed. See below on how I would like this thing to work:

I am interested in creating an app that has multiple SQLite databases which are already created and that the app will need to access, there will be 5-6 Database it needs to access. I will never have to enter data into these databases, they will be read only  There is one set feature and that would be that all SQLite DBs will be internal to the phone. please note that I am NOT asking for a full program just steer me in the right direction, web pages, books, maybe some helpfull code etc.  any help would be much appreciated.

This is my plan on how it would work

--1-- The app would first ask which school we are trying to access. (on click the app would open the the correct DB)

--2-- Next the app would ask for Student Name (on click the app will look at the column part of the DB.)

--3-- Next The app would ask for the Birthday (on click the app will look at the row part of the DB.)

--4-- Last the app would then provide the student ID number.

Comment: You have searched??? come on, there are thousands of tutorials on how to use a SQLite database. Try better.

Comment: You are right there are many, but 99.9% of the info is creating a db on the phone, not about having an existing one.  Thank you for your comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with your questions, try something and then ask- where you get stuck or face some problem. Code Specific issues would be better at SO.
Assuming that you are a beginner...If the databases are going to be inside your app, locating the db won't be a problem else need to consider that.

Rest for your requirements, you'l need to access db, retrieve information and show it in listviews, probably. There are other building blocks of android- you should go through them for the UI of your app.
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/index.html

Check for ListView, Db, and maybe Cursor Adapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes I am a newbie.  I have actually already created the screens using HTML5, Dreamweaver, but I don't like the performance.  It seems to drag sometimes.  I don't think I can use Java and HTML5, I am guessing, all the searches come up to Java Script.  I think I will be better off creating the app in Eclipse, what is your opinion?

Comment: Yes, native approach would be better. Eclipse plus android sdk, *if java script then PhoneGap actually